# MySQL INSERT INGORE SELECT weird behaviour

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have been using a query to add editable profiles based on an original user table.

The original registration table has the fields, id - name - surname - username - password - email - confirmation

The profile has several more customizable fields, but the ones I am inserting into the profiles table from the users table is, id - name - email.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO profile(cid,display_name,display_email)
SELECT id,name,email FROM users
```

This used to work for a couple of years now, but recently I noticed that the profiles table has topped inserting profiles when users register. When I run the query in phpmyadmin it just says 0 rows inserted.

Can someone please help me to figure out why this is happening? Updates to MySQL that I missed or something :(

Comment: What unique indexes exist on the `profile` table?

Comment: `PRIMARY id
UNIQUE cid`

Comment: Try running the SELECT part only, see if there are any results. Also try running it without `IGNORE`, that should tell you the reason its not inserted.

Comment: SELECT runs fine. Ok, I have noticed that there is a row 0 in the profile table. I delete this row, run the query and it inserts one row, randomly from the SELECT in the users table. It seems for some reason it is now adding a row 0 and after that, it fails to add the rest. The profile table already has several entries, just as note, since I have been using this query for more than 2 years now without problems, until recently.

Comment: How many records on the profiles table? What data type is the cdi column?

Comment: @Vatec, if I remove the IGNORE it just gives me "#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" - As stated before, I never had this problem before and now suddenly it's adding a Row 0.

Comment: @kickstart I am working on a sample of the database to try and resolve the problem, there are only the first 19 rows in the table at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

It would seem my host for some reason, during upgrades changed my table field id on the profiles table to a defined value of 0.

I edited the structured and set it back to auto_increment. Which was the reason the query stopped adding the new values.

Thank you to everyone that questioned me, it pointed me towards the problem and helped to resolve this issue.